# AppLocker and UAC on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, uac

Using the feature:"Local Security Policy-> Application Control Policies->AppLocker->Executable Rules->Create default Rules" will create a rule:

Allow   BUILTIN\Administrators   All Files

On Windows7 when logged in as a user that is a member of the administrator group AppLocker will still be blocking programs from running, but if I right click and press the "run as administrator" AppLocker will not block the program from running. I assume the reason is because UAC normally filters the access token.

On Windows8 with the same rules AppLocker will NOT block me from running applications the same way it does on Windows7. Why? How can I make windows8 behave the same way as windows7?

Comment: I can look around, but I thought people were complaining to MS about the way 7 handled it because of UAC and wanted it "fixed" in 8 so that it works as you would expect it to (by not blocking because of your allow rule).  I'll see if I can find proof that is what happened.

Comment: The way it worked in win7 would require a browser exploit or phishing campaign  to also do a UAC-bypass to be able to be successfully exceute a binary or load a dll. I really liked this extra layer of security. The way it works by default in win8 leaves no extra protection for members of the admin group. I would like it to work in a similar way as in win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have encountered this same issue.  We didn't "fix" the issue but constructed a pretty good work around.
1. delete the "BUILTIN\Administrators All Files" rule
2. Create a file on the root of C called AppLockerBypass (or something of that nature)
3. Create a rule to allow administrators to allow anything in the AppLockerBypass folder to run.

Now, when you want to "Run As Administrator" you must put the file in that folder.

If you can't put the file in that folder, then create a rule for that specific app.